# Is there a way to tell where synclient gets its information from?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, macbook, input-devices

I have a Macbook 2,1 running Mint Katya and the touchpad config has been driving me nuts. xorg.conf seems to be ignored, so for now I've just been getting rid of it.

Running `synclient`, I can get things how I want them, but what's interesting is that it's clearly pulling the information from somewhere other than xorg.conf, or xorg.conf.d/synclient .

I've got just about every touchpad configurator in the known universe on here, and also have a bunch of DE's installed, so it's impossible for me to tell what's "canon", so to speak.

xorg.conf is currently blank.

xorg.conf.d synclient.d is as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection
```

I've also got the mactel support libraries installed, but I can't figure out where the actual settings for `appletouch` are.

Can anyone lend a hand? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

Apparently what seems most "canonical", at least on my machine, is `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` .

The "wrong" values that were being refreshed each boot (and that `synclient` was reading from) appear to be `appletouch` or `synaptics` defaults (could be wrong on this now, god knows I've muddied the waters on this machine plenty).

In any case, turns out you can put whatever options you *been told* belong in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` into `50-synaptics.conf` as well.

Once again, this is on Mint 11 Katya (so for anyone having this problem on other distros, the file paths may be slightly different).

Updated `50-synaptics.conf` for Macbook 2,1 (Early 2007) is as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad catchall"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

# These settings for FingerLow and High give a very light touch on this model, 
# similar to what you see on a Boot Camp Windows partition. Defaults to 29 and 34 
# on my machine.

    Option "FingerLow" "5" 
    Option "FingerHigh" "15"

# Next option seems to fix "jumpy cursor" problem, where a steady motion from 
# the user does not result in steady pointer movement (skips a few pixels at a 
# time). Defaults to 0.

    Option "JumpyCursorThreshold" "5" 
EndSection
```

Hopes this helps people in the future.

Comment: Doesnt work for TapButton2 options, however, there check out this solution http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/11/06/persistent-touchpad-configuration-in-ubuntu-11-10/